# How to get the details of the pressed list Item?

Tags: sapui5

I've build a table, that it looks as following:

[image]

and the code:

```
<ColumnListItem type="Detail" detailPress="onDetailPress">
    <cells>
        <ObjectIdentifier title="{Customer>CustomerID}" text="{Customer>CompanyName}"/>
        <Text text="{Customer>ContactName}"/>
        <Text text="{Customer>Address}"/>
        <Text text="{Customer>City}"/>
    </cells>
</ColumnListItem>
```

When I press on the pencil, it will emit the event `detailPress`:

```
    onDetailPress: function(oEvent) {
        console.log(oEvent.getParameters());
    }
```

What is the return type `getParameters()` method call on the event object? The [doc](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ColumnListItem/methods/getCells) does not mention any type.

How can I get the Customer details of the pressed list item using the oEvent.

The debugger says:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to know the type(details) of the item clicked? What is that you want to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to get the `CustomerID` value of clicked cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the object that is bound to the row like this

```
onDetailPress: function(oEvent) {
    var oObject = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("Customer").getObject();
    // from this object, you can do oObject.CustomerID
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The oEvent is the event object. getParameters() returns a JSON Object. So the type is Object as stated [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListItemBase/events/detailPress)

In this case it is an empty object, but there are other event which return parameters inside the object like for example [this one](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/events/parseError)

If you want to get the customerID just get the model path from the clicked row and get the property from the model. Here the snippet:

```
onDetailPress: function(oEvent){
    var oColumnListItem = oEvent.getSource();
    var sPath = oColumnListItem.getBindingContext("Customer").getPath();
    var sCustomerIDPath = sPath + "/CustomerID";
    var oModel = oColumnListItem.getModel("Customer")
    console.log(oModel.getProperty(sCustomerIDPath));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the row object by accessing the `getSource` of `oEvent` object:

```
oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("Customer").getObject();
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for information on how to improve your answer.